# What part of speech is "before" in the phrase "before we meet again"?

Tags: parts-of-speech, reasoning

Identify the part of speech of the word in bold:

> It will be five years **before** we meet again.

4 options:

- Preposition
- Adverb
- Conjuction
- Adjective

Now, According to my knowledge, "before" is an adverb. However the correct answer was - conjunction. What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Traditionally, it's referred to as a "subordinating conjunction" because it introduces a subordinate clause.

But in modern grammar, it's analyzed as a preposition that takes a clause rather than a noun phrase as a complement.

Comment: Hooray, an accurate answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that there are multiple terminologies that use the same words to stand for different things. Almost certainly the OP is asking about traditional grammar. "Modern" (that is, scientific, esoteric) grammar uses the word "preposition" to denote words of a kind that in common usage are not called prepositions, such as "[home](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/385474/74898)".

Answer (score 1):

The word "**before**" is a preposition here. Refer to [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/before) and [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/before) for grammar.

**Before** means *During the period of time preceding (a particular event or time)* and here's the explanation [**English Grammar Today**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/before):

**Before as a preposition**

> We use before most commonly with noun phrases to refer to timed events.

However, "[EnglishPractice](https://www.englishpractice.com/words/preposition-conjunction/)" says that it is a conjunction here.

> As a conjunction before means ‘previously to the time when’. The conjunction before joins two clauses together. Note that before and its clause can come either before or after the other clause. In subordinate clauses introduced by before we use a present tense to refer to the future.

- I will call you before I go. (**NOT** I will call you before I will go.)

Comment: Oxford Dictionary doesn't support your argument though. Apparently, there hasn't yet a dictionary analyzing "before+clause" as a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, before is acting as a conjunction because it would be putting two clauses together, but in that phrase there aren't two clauses so its not a complete sentence. if it was a complete sentence however, it would say, we will do "this" before we meet again. Here it is acting as a conjunction by putting the two clauses together